# Error while running cloud9 "error: ld terminated with signal 11"

Tags: llvm, cloud9-ide, binutils, klee

I am trying to run the cloud9 application on ubuntu. However make command is giving me error

```
llvm[2]: Linking Release+Asserts executable klee (without symbols)
collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
make[2]: *** [/home/mmalik9/cloud9-cloudsuite/cloud9/Release+Asserts/bin/klee] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mmalik9/cloud9-cloudsuite/cloud9/tools/klee'
make[1]: *** [klee/.makeall] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mmalik9/cloud9-cloudsuite/cloud9/tools'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Please give any idea how to solve this issue?

PS Update from https://askubuntu.com/questions/441621/cloud9-application-is-giving-error-error-ld-terminated-with-signal-11-segment

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o proj
```

> I am getting same error "`collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped`

Comment: duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/441621/cloud9-application-is-giving-error-error-ld-terminated-with-signal-11-segment  The problem is in `ld` program from binutils. I think, there can be some limit (`ulimit`), which kills ld... Please, add exact version of your ubuntu, and how you downloaded and configured the `cloud9 application`

Comment: Is it possible that my gcc/g++ link is broken. As I just have tried a simple helloworld program to run using g++ and it is giving me the same error.

Comment: user2805242, Hmm, try reboot, reinstalling binutils package, and memtest.

Comment: thanks @osgx that has solved the problem

Comment: which action? Reboot, reinstall or memtest (with memory replacement)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't run the ld even for simplest programs (like helloworld), it seems like something (ld binary or its libraries) was corrupted, either in memory (reboot will help), or on the hard drive.

You can recheck md5sums of the installed packages (in rpm-based linuxes - `rpm --verify`; in deb-based - [`debsums`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/debsums.1.html) or `dpkg --verify` - according to [debian bug 187019](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=187019)), or simply reinstall them.

With `memtest` you can test RAM for defects (ECC RAM is better to protect your data). And with modern filesystems, having [data checksumming](http://nerdbynature.de/s9y/?325) (ZFS, btrfs) and/or  integrity checkers like AIDE you can detect silent corruption of data, stored on your harddrive.